# S3 Copy artifacts with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use the [S3 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin) in a Jenkins 2.0 pipeline with a Jenkinsfile. Unfortunately, the pipeline syntax helper does not seem to be very complete.

I got the following code :

```
step([$class: 'S3CopyArtifact', buildSelector: [$class: 'StatusBuildSelector', stable: true], excludeFilter: '', filter: 'deploy/*.zip', flatten: false, optional: false, projectName: 'my/project/with/folders', target: '/my/directory/'])
```

Off course this is not sufficient, as credentials and bucket are missing. Additionnaly, this plugin does not seem to behave correctly with the Folders plugin.

Does anyone have hints on this ?

Comment: Actually the pipeline syntax helper IS complete, but I had bot S3CopyArtifact and S3BucketPublisher. The one to use is *S3BucketPublisher* !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with your original statement in that the script generation is oh so **sad**. It does not give enough to go on, even when you have `S3BucketPublisher` selected.
See my snippet below.  It assumes you've created a profile already in the system configuration.

```
stage("publish to s3") {
    step([
        $class: 'S3BucketPublisher',
        entries: [[
            sourceFile: 'mybinaryFile',
            bucket: 'GoBinaries',
            selectedRegion: 'eu-west-1',
            noUploadOnFailure: true,
            managedArtifacts: true,
            flatten: true,
            showDirectlyInBrowser: true,
            keepForever: true,
        ]],
        profileName: 'myprofile',
        dontWaitForConcurrentBuildCompletion: false, 
    ])
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible with the same approach to upload a whole folder?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing but I still have errors. I'll keep you posted

Comment: @djsd123 is it possible to uplaod a string the same way

Comment: Sorry, @MadhuAvinash, I am not sure what you mean by upload a string? Typically, one might use the plugin to upload/publish artefacts. If you're having issues? Please post the resulting output and what you're trying to achieve and I/anyone will be more than happy to assist. Bear in mind that I have not used Jenkins in some time.

Comment: I want to catch exceptions in this class.
If I just add a try&catch block around the "step" It does not catch the error.
What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

For a simpler use case this is now supported in [Pipeline AWS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+AWS+Plugin) like this:
    `s3Upload(file:'someFolder', bucket:'my-bucket', path:'/path/to/targetFolder/')`

djsd123's example works perfectly for more advanced use cases.
If you also want to add metadata tags to your objects you can add a userMetaData array:

```
    profileName: 'myprofile',
    dontWaitForConcurrentBuildCompletion: false, 
    userMetadata: [[ key: 'git_branch', value: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"],
                   [ key: 'build_number', value: "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"]
    ],
```

Comment: I used the AWS CLI with `sh` blocks, but this is clearly mothe in the philosophy, I'll progressively switch to this plugin. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

adding on @djsd123 answer, you can upload a folder using glob patterns:

```
                    ...
                    bucket: "bucketName/folder",
                    sourceFile: 'folder/**',
                    ...
```